# submit a $_GET variable as a submit button is clicked

Tags: mysql, variables, button, get, submit

I am trying to send over a variable which contains id of a user to another page.

First page is the form page where the user enter it's details and as soon as the submit button is clicked the details are entered into the table,

next the first page redirects to a page where user's asked to upload it's display picture, and to store the path to that picture i need the id on that very page i.e. on the image upload page.

Can someone tell me how can i achieve this?

Comment: or a session variable perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurred to me you may actually be asking how you can get the last inserted id from the recently inserted photo you're adding via mysql. In that case you can use

```
$lastId = mysql_insert_id ($yourConnection);
```

(details at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)
(if you're using mysqli http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

to find the id. Do this after inserting and before closing the connection. Then pass the id along however when you redirect:

```
header('Location: yournextpage.php?id=' . $lastId);
```

The id will then be available as a GET variable: $_GET['id']

OR if you're asking how you can get the id from a form (assuming PHP), do this:

```
<form method="get" action="yournextpage.php">
    <input type="text" name="id">User ID here</input>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue"></input>
</form>
```

The value of the first input box will be stored as $_GET['id'] or whatever you have as the 'name' attribute.

Comment: i'm sorry i forgot that part but yes that is PHP

Comment: lets suppose then one user is in the process of registering, and meanwhile somewhere else there is another user who completes his registration process before the previous one , in that case the last id would be given out for the user who completed the registration first which would be wrong

Comment: mysql_insert_id functions on a per connection basis. You would create a new connection for that other user and thus no race condition should result.

Comment: i'm not doubting you but are you absolutely sure that there won't be any such possibility?

Comment: "The value of mysql_insert_id() is affected only by statements issued within the current client connection. It is not affected by statements issued by other clients." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-insert-id.html

Comment: thanks a ton ! can you tell me what should be there in place of $yourConnection, i'm kinda confused

Comment: I don't know exactly how you're handling your mysql, but you should have a link object you created when you opened a connection to the mysql server. That link object would go into the function there. If you're using object oriented style in mysqli (recommended) I believe you just do $link->insert_id

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, when you redirect to the second page, you would pass in the ID on the URL. So, instead of this for your redirect:

```
header('Location: /upload-image.php', TRUE, 303);
```

You do this (where $id is the ID from the current form):

```
header("Location: /upload-image.php?id=$id", TRUE, 303);
```

On the upload-image page, you would simply read this in with `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: i'm using this command to redirect to the image upload page, can this be altered such as on the next page i can retrieve the id using GET or something like that?

Comment: @user1216752, exactly. You are setting it in the redirect URL, and you can retrieve it on the next page with `$_GET`. If this is a user ID though, forget everything I said. It should be stored in the session. You can't trust the user to provide you with the right user ID. All security depends on only applying updates to the logged in user's data.

Comment: damn! i forgot to tell you which command i am using it's this one:


window.location = "../cropupload/jquery_upload_cropv1.2/upload_dp.php";

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally $_POST is used for this, but if you wanted to use $_GET you could change the form method .